# Find occurences of list in a list of list in a dataframe column

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe, df, with one column.

```
data = {'details': [['brand : honda', 'car : city', 'colour : black'],['brand : toyota', 'car : innova'],
                    ['brand : honda', 'colour : red'], ['brand : toyota', 'car : corolla', 'colour : white', 'type : sedan']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns= ['details'])
df
```

I want to split the dataframe into different columns and get a dataframe that looks like this -

```
data = {'details': [['brand : honda', 'car : city', 'colour : black'],['brand : toyota', 'car : innova'],
                    ['brand : honda', 'colour : red'], ['brand : toyota', 'car : corolla', 'colour : white', 'type : sedan']],
        'brand': ['honda', 'toyota', 'honda', 'toyota'],
        'car': ['city','innova','','corolla'],
        'colour': ['black','','red','white'],
        'type': ['','','','sedan']
        }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns= ['details', 'brand', 'car', 'colour', 'type'])
df2
```

I tried the following but it did not work -

```
a2 = []
b2 = []
c2 = []
d2 = []
for i in df['details']:
    for j in range(len(i)):
        if 'brand :' in i[j]:
            print 'lalala'
            a1 = i[j]
            a2.append(a1)
        else:
            a1 = ''
            a2.append(a1)
        if 'car :' in i[j]:
            print 'lalala'
            b1 = i[j]
            b2.append(b1)
        else:
            b1 = ''
            b2.append(b1)
        if 'colour :' in i[j]:
            c1 = i[j]
            c2.append(c1)
        else:
            c1 = ''
            c2.append(c1)
        if 'type :' in i[j]:
            d1 = i[j]
            d2.append(d1)
        else:
            d1 = ''
            d2.append(d1)
df['brand'] = a2
df['car'] = b2
df['colour'] = c2
df['type'] = d2
```

Please help as I have hit a major roadbloack.

Comment: It would be a lot easier transform the dictionary details into a list based on the key first and then pass the data in.

Comment: It helps to have the details about what language and library versions etc.. listed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following assuming the details types are known:

```
details_types = ['brand', 'car', 'colour', 'type']

for x in details_types :
    df[x] = None

for idx, value in df.iterrows(): 
    for col_details in df.iloc[idx, 0]:
        feature = col_details.replace(' ', '').split(':')[0]
        value = col_details.replace(' ', '').split(':')[1]
        df.iloc[idx, list(df.columns).index(feature)] = value
```

**Output**

```
|   |                      details                      | brand  |   car   | colour | type  |
|---|---------------------------------------------------|--------|---------|--------|-------|
| 0 | [brand : honda, car : city, colour : black]       | honda  | city    | black  | None  |
| 1 | [brand : toyota, car : innova]                    | toyota | innova  | None   | None  |
| 2 | [brand : honda, colour : red]                     | honda  | None    | red    | None  |
| 3 | [brand : toyota, car : corolla, colour : white... | toyota | corolla | white  | sedan |
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler approach might be the following -

```
data = {'details': [['brand : honda', 'car : city', 'colour : black'],['brand : toyota', 'car : innova'],
                    ['brand : honda', 'colour : red'], ['brand : toyota', 'car : corolla', 'colour : white', 'type : sedan']]}

#takes a string and returns a dict based on ':'
def fix(l):
    return dict(s.split(':') for s in l)

#flatten and fix the lists of lists to get a list of dicts
dicts = [fix(i) for sublist in data.values() for i in sublist]

#Add the lists into a single dataframe (optional add the 'Details' column)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicts)
df['details'] = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)  #adding 'Details' col
print(df)
```

```
    brand       car  colour    type   \
0    honda      city   black     NaN   
1   toyota    innova     NaN     NaN   
2    honda       NaN     red     NaN   
3   toyota   corolla   white   sedan   

                                             details  
0        [brand : honda, car : city, colour : black]  
1                     [brand : toyota, car : innova]  
2                      [brand : honda, colour : red]  
3  [brand : toyota, car : corolla, colour : white...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import ChainMap
data = {'details': [['brand : honda', 'car : city', 'colour : black'],['brand : toyota', 'car : innova'],
                ['brand : honda', 'colour : red'], ['brand : toyota', 'car : corolla', 'colour : white', 'type : sedan']]}
#STEP_1
lists=[[{y.split(':')[0]:y.split(':')[1]} for y in x] for x in data['details']]
#STEP_2
data_df = [dict(ChainMap(*x)) for x in lists]
#STEP_3
data_df=pd.DataFrame(data_df)
#STEP_4
data_df['details']=data['details']
print(data_df)
'''Explanation:
STEP_1: It creates list of lists with dictionary elements

[[{'brand ': ' honda'}, {'car ': ' city'}, {'colour ': ' black'}],
[{'brand ': ' toyota'}, {'car ': ' innova'}],
[{'brand ': ' honda'}, {'colour ': ' red'}],
[{'brand ': ' toyota'},
{'car ': ' corolla'},
{'colour ': ' white'},
{'type ': ' sedan'}]]

STEP_2: It is to convert list of lists to list of dictionaries

[{'colour ': ' black', 'car ': ' city', 'brand ': ' honda'},
{'car ': ' innova', 'brand ': ' toyota'},
{'colour ': ' red', 'brand ': ' honda'},
{'type ': ' sedan',
'colour ': ' white',
'car ': ' corolla',
'brand ': ' toyota'}]

STEP_3: As we can directly create a dataframe from list of 
dictionaries, it creates a dataframe with 4 columns that are brand, 
car, color & type

STEP_4: Add the column 'details' using the 'data' variable'''
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

- [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode) + [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract) to extract the patterns
- [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) + [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas-dataframe-fillna) to convert to the expected format

**Code**

```
# extract the patterns
pattern = r"(?:brand : (?P<brand>\w+))|(?:car : (?P<car>\w+))|(?:colour : (?P<colour>\w+))|(?:type : (?P<type>\w+))"
expanded = df.explode("details")["details"].str.extract(pattern)

# convert to expected format after extracting the patterns
new = expanded.groupby(level=0).first().fillna("")
print(new)
```

**Output**

```
    brand      car colour   type
0   honda     city  black       
1  toyota   innova              
2   honda             red       
3  toyota  corolla  white  sedan
```

After you can concat all together by doing:

```
result = pd.concat([df, new], axis=1)
print(result)
```

**Output** *(full)*

```
                                             details   brand  ... colour   type
0        [brand : honda, car : city, colour : black]   honda  ...  black       
1                     [brand : toyota, car : innova]  toyota  ...              
2                      [brand : honda, colour : red]   honda  ...    red       
3  [brand : toyota, car : corolla, colour : white...  toyota  ...  white  sedan

[4 rows x 5 columns]
```